# Jenkins Changelog update manually in Pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins pipeline script currently uses manually svn update as shell command instead of SCM Checkout methods. I'm trying to manually update the Jenkins log as a part of the build step. I'm trying to get the changes of my svn update command and inject the same in jenkins changelog. .

### **Here is the list of pipeline steps what I've tried**

- dummy checkout step *(#I'm doing this so that changelog is generated and have the SCM step enabled)*
- svn update *(#Update directory using svn update command)*
- Generate a changelog xml based on the output from the svn update
  command #I'm doing this with the help of python script called from
  the pipeline.
- Now I replace the existing changelog xml with the generated changelog
  xml.

When I run pipeline script, the dashboard shows as 'No changes'. But when I restart the jenkins instance, The changes are displayed in the dashboard which shows the changes in the generated XML.

Kindly advise. Any other workarounds are also fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Jenkins by executing the .war file. The issue was not found when I recreated the same pipeline steps with Jenkins installation set up as *windows service*. So better to go with standard installation.